# how to bend border's of a div

Tags: html, css, border

i have a div i want the border not to be flat but bended how to do it

Current div

```css
div{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background:#000;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Here the border are flat i want it bended

Comment: You don't mean [rounded corners](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_borders.asp) do you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using `border-radius` And You can Change `border-radius: px`

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/m4wo1b8m/)

Answer (score 1):

This might help to you...

Use `border-radius`

```css
div{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background:#000;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius:4px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

using **border-radius**

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My version differs from the others, right? )

```css
div{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background:#000;
  
  border-radius: 50%/10%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```